# Confused about what pattern to use to block threads conditionally

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm having a `Map` object that could be `null` or simply cleared when the application first starts. I need all threads accessing this map to block till the map is initialized and only then I need to signal all threads to access this map.

This map holds configuration data and it will be for reading only unless a single threads decides to refresh to load new configuration data (So it doesn't need to `Synchronized` for the sake of performance as I don't find necessary too). I tried using a `Condition` object for a `ReentrantLock` but it threw `IllegalMonitorState` exceptions whenever I tried to `signalAll()` or `await()`.

Here is a pseudo code for what I need to do:

```
void monitorThread{
    while(someCondition){
        map = updatedMap();
        condition.signalAll();
    }
}

String readValueFromMap(String key){
    if(map == null){
        condition.await();
    }
    return map.get(key);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not need a `synchronize` block? Seems if execution of `if (map == null)` is not atomic, some thread may miss wake up signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this right, you need a memory barrier hence the `volatile`.  Because the map may be null initially, you are going to need another lock object.  The following should work:

```
private final Object lockObject = new Object();
private volatile Map<...> map;

void monitorThread{
    while (condition){
        // do this outside of the synchronized in case it takes a while
        Map<...> updatedMap = updatedMap();
        synchronized (lockObject) {
           map = updatedMap;
           // notify everyone that may be waiting for the map to be initialized
           lockObject.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

String readValueFromMap(String key) {
    // we grab a copy of the map to avoid race conditions in case the map is
    // updated in the future
    Map<...> mapRef = map;
    // we have a while loop here to handle spurious signals
    if (mapRef == null) {
        synchronized (lockObject) {
           while (map == null) {
               // wait for the map to initialized
               lockObject.wait();
           }
           mapRef = map;
        }
    }
    return mapRef.get(key);
}
```

Comment: with map volatile, I'm not sure you need the copy

Comment: Maybe not @assylias.  I was worried that the update would happen again.

Comment: The update will happen many times. Your solution would force that only one thread being able to read from the map which could hit the performance as the whole application uses this map for configuration values. Am I correct ?

Comment: No @muhammad, in my solution, if the `map` is `null` then the readers will all wait on the `lockObject`.  Once the `map` is updated, they will all be notified.   I just tweaked the while loop there.

Comment: @Gray, ya it now looks it would work. You're having the `wait()` call in a loop as a defense mechanism, correct ? What do you think is foolproof and better with performance, you approach or AmitD's (I'll have to re-initialize the `CountdownLatch` object to sustain multiple map updates) ? Thank you.

Comment: It worked the last way too @muhammad.  Yes it is in a wait as a defense mechanism.   Putting the `wait()` in a loop is a recommended pattern.

Answer (score 4):

`CountDownLatch` is all you need.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

While initialize hashmap do `latch.countdown()` and in threads use `latch.await()`

```
void monitorThread{
    map = updatedMap();
    latch.countDown();
}

String readValueFromMap(String key){
    latch.await();
    return map.get(key);
}
```

Please note that CountDownLatch `await()` method only waits if countdown is greater than 0 hence only first time.

Comment: I did not downvote but you might want to add a few lines of explanations.

Comment: I am adding it but typing from mobile so I was bit slow.

Comment: But wouldn't this pause all the threads, even if they don't currently read from the map at the moment of the refresh?

Comment: +1 it's a simple and effective approach (you probably mean to call `latch.await()` in the `readValueFromMap` method).

Comment: +1 This does fail however if the user wants to create/update the map more then once.

Comment: I really like your approach and @John Vint is correct I will need to do this more than once. I guess I'd have to re-initialize the `CountdownLatch` with the value of one after each update. What do you think ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Are you using Java 7?  If you are you can use a `Phaser`.  It handles the 'recreate' part by using a phase (which is the current iteration of all parties arriving to a particular barrier).

Comment: @JohnVint, no I'm not. Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Yes. Reinitialize `CountDownLatch` after every map initialization.

Comment: Re-initializing the latch caused issues such as leaving some threads blocking with an unreferenced instance of the latch and I couldn't find a proper way\location to release the latch before re-initializing it. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you need is a "Lock" object that guards access to the Map.

These are pretty easy to use:

```
 Lock l = ...;
 l.lock();
 try {
     // access the resource protected by this lock
 } finally {
     l.unlock();
 }
```

You could probably use: java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock